# Named Range Can't Be Deleted After Small Code Change

Tags: excel, vba

I recently split my code into two sections to stop the date automatically being entered, as on a Monday, we need to do 3 days worth of data

All I did was Add a new sub and redefine the variables - now i can't delete a named range

My code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Import()

Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRowC As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Report")
lastRowC = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' bottom populated cell of Column "C", plus 1

    With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;N:\Operations\001 Daily Management\Cemex\FMSQRY.CSV", Destination:= _
            ws.Cells(lastRowC, 3))
        .Name = "FMSQRY"
        ' etc
        ' etc
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook
        .Connections("FMSQRY").Delete
        .Names("FMSQRY").Delete
    End With

End Sub




Sub TodaysDate()

Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRowC As Long, lastRowH As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Report")

lastRowH = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' bottom populated cell of Column "H", plus 1
lastRowC = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row ' bottom populated cell of Column "C"

    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(lastRowH, 8), ws.Cells(lastRowC, 8))
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

So nothing to do with the Named Range was actually touched

`.Name = "FMSQRY"` still names my range, but when `.Names("FMSQRY").Delete` comes around I get a 1004 Error

[image: Named Range]

[image: Debug]

---

ANSWER:

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    .Connections("FMSQRY").Delete
    With ws
        .Names("FMSQRY").Delete
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Name is on sheet-level and not Workbook-level.(you could have the same name on different sheets)

so:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").Names("FMSQRY").Delete
```

Comment: this will cause an error. No need to use Sheet - Level

Comment: The scope of FMSQRY is in OP on sheet-level, not workbook, so without referring to the sheet it will throw an 1004 error

Comment: This worked - I was under the same assumption as @Error1004 that this was at WB level not WS. I've updated my answer with the correct code - which is similar to this

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why that code doesn't work.

But if you write code like below then it works...

```
Dim nm As Name
For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If nm.Name = "FMSQRY" Then nm.Delete
Next nm
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code without the `.connections`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook
        .Names("FMSQRY").Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I needed the .connections as that's a separate function that also needs to be deleted